# Python bs4 removes br tag

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I use bs4 to manipulate some rich-text. but it removes br tag inside where i did character conversion. below is the simple form of the code.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#source_code = self.textInput.toHtml()
source_code =  """.......<p style=" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"><span style=" font-family:'Ubuntu';">ABC ABC<br />ABC</span></p>.......""" 

soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code, "lxml")

for elm in soup.find_all('span', style=re.compile(r"font-family:'Ubuntu'")):
#actually there was a for loop
    elm.string = elm.text.replace("A", "X")
    elm.string = elm.text.replace("B", "Y")
    elm.string = elm.text.replace("C", "Z")

print(soup.prettify())
```

this should give an output as

```
...<span style=" font-family:'Ubuntu';">XYZ XYZ<br />XYZ</span>...
#XYZ XYZ
#XYZ
```

but it gives output without br tag.

```
...<span style=" font-family:'Ubuntu';">XYZ XYZXYZ</span>...
#XYZ XYZXYZ
```

how can i correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are redefining the `.string` of the element, but instead I would find the "text" nodes and made the replacement there:

```
for text in elm.find_all(text=True):
    text.replace_with(text.replace("A", "X").replace("B", "Y").replace("C", "Z"))
```

Works for me, produces:

```
</p>
  <p style=" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;">
   <span style=" font-family:'Ubuntu';">
    XYZ XYZ
    <br/>
    XYZ
   </span>
</p>
```

> how can i include this part in a loop?

Here is a sample:

```
replacements = {
    "A": "X",
    "B": "Y",
    "C": "Z"
}
for text in elm.find_all(text=True):
    text_to_replace = text
    for k, v in replacements.items():
        text_to_replace = text_to_replace.replace(k, v)

    text.replace_with(text_to_replace)
```

Comment: thank you so much alecxe! but one quick question, how can i include this part in a loop?  
    text.replace_with(text.replace("A", "X").replace("B", "Y").replace("C", "Z"))  
it gives an error 
    File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bs4/element.py", line 211, in replace_with  
    my_index = self.parent.index(self)  
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'  
  
thank you again!